# Count Features using WFST-Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wfs-t

I have basic point data and I want to count the number of points in the data. I am displaying the data using WFST-Leaflet since I need to also apply filters and this plugin seems like the cleanest method.

```
const wfstPointOptions = {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    showExisting: true,
    geometryField: 'geom',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs',
    typeNS: 'HEC',
    typeName: 'Universities',
    maxFeatures: 100,
    opacity: 1,
    style: function(layer) {
        return {
            color: 'purple',
            weight: 1
        }
    },
};

const wfstPoint = new L.WFST(wfstPointOptions, new L.Format.GeoJSON({
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    pointToLayer(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
        const layer = new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 5,
        });
        
    return layer;
    },
}));

wfstPoint.addTo(map);
```

How do I count the number of features in this layer?

Comment: Change the request type to hits and make sure you are using wfs2.0

Comment: Can you explain please? What do you mean by request type to hits?

Comment: Instead of request=GetFeature use request=hits

Comment: You need to generate a request like: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=Universities&resulttype=hits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.WFST` layer fires `load` event when all features are loaded, so you just have to catch the event and get number of layers from event object (assuming all features are points):

```
wfstPoint.on('load', function(evt) {
  console.log('Points: ', evt.layers.length);
});
```